# Snapping Preview windows with BetterTouchTool make search buggy

Tags: macos, preview, window-manager, bettertouchtool

I use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) in order to be able to maximise windows to half the screen by dragging them agains the edge of the screen. When I do this with Preview windows and then attempt to search in the document, the user interface gets messed up, so I have no `Done` button to get rid of the search results. See below gif for illustration. There should be a `Done` button at the upper right.

[image]

Can anybody confirm this weirdness? Is this a BTT bug or can I do anything myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall this software does Preview behave?

It is likely an interaction with Preview and this software. And *maybe* something else on your system. I would suggest contacting support on this product directly.